# How to disable container jobs in an Azure DevOps private agent pool

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am running jobs in Azure DevOps release pipeline with a private agent.

However, it appears that the jobs run inside a container within the private agent. This was setup inadvertently. 
I confirmed this to some extend, by issuing 'hostname' 'ipconfig' etc. in my job and these gives some virtual names (SCW00000xx) and IPs that are different from my actual private agent host.
Because of this my pipeline tasks cannot access some domain resources and other tasks which otherwise works fine when executed directly (tested in RDP session) on the private host.

Is there a way for me to configure my job to run in the actual physical host rather than a container without having to redeploy the private agent?
Some demands or conditions that I can use?

Comment: When you configured the agent, it was in container or not?

Comment: No, as far as i know and it was never the goal. This was the package used. https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.150.3/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.150.3.zip
It was created as a deployment group, not sure if that defaults to container.